# How to affix a file-name in a box to the corner of a listing environment?

Tags: listings, code

I'm writing a series of lecture notes and, because I'm working with multiple source files, I'd like to affix the current file name in the top-right of my listing environments. Here's an example of what I would like:

[image]

I've tried looking at the tcolorbox package, but it looks a bit too daunting to dive into.

MWE:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=MyC]
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void) {
    printf("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

With an accompanying `lstdefinelanguage`:

```
\lstdefinelanguage{MyC}{%
    numbers=left,
    xleftmargin=5mm,
    framexleftmargin=5mm,
    commentstyle=\color{orange},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    morekeywords=[1]{NULL},
    language=C,
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
    showstringspaces=false,
    frame=single,
    escapeinside={(*;}{;*)}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! SInce there exist different approaches to typeset listings, it would be nice if you could provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces the above picture (without the box with the file name). This will help to come up with a solution that suits your needs.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the package `tcolorbox`, you could do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings, skins}

\newtcblisting{mylisting}[1]{
    enhanced,
    colback=white,
    colframe=black,
    sharp corners,
    boxrule=0.4pt,
    left=0pt,
    right=0pt,
    top=-6pt,
    bottom=-6pt,
    oversize,
    listing only,
    listing options={
        numbers=left,
        xleftmargin=5mm,
        commentstyle=\color{orange},
        keywordstyle=\color{blue},
        stringstyle=\color{red},
        morekeywords={NULL},
        language=C,
        basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
        breaklines=true,
        showstringspaces=false,
        escapeinside={(*;}{;*)}
    },
    overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \node[draw, anchor={north east}] at (frame.north east) {#1};
    \end{tcbclipinterior}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylisting}{main.c}
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void) {
    printf("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
\end{mylisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]